# Using Azure CLI in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-cli

I'm trying to use the Jenkins pipeline with Azure using this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/execute-cli-jenkins-pipeline with the exception that I have Jenkins on localhost (running Win7).

The build works as expected, but deployment fails on the line in Jenkinsfile where the 'az login...' script should run, with a 'command not found' error.

```
 withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('...')]) {
      sh '''
        'az login ..'
```

I am able to use the 'az' commands in the command line outside of Jenkins.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Azure service principal to Jenkins credential. Please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/execute-cli-jenkins-pipeline#add-azure-service-principal-to-jenkins-credential) you provided.

If you don't have a service principal, you could use Azure CLI 2.0 to create a new. Please refer to this [link:Create an Azure service principal with Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest).

```
withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('<mySrvPrincipal>')])
```

`<mySrcvPrincipal>` is credential id you set.

[image]

Note:

When you add Azure service principal to Jenkins credential, click Verify Service Principal, please ensure you also see **Successfully verified the Microsoft Azure Service Principal.**

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning it, but I did add the service principal as the very first thing (following the tutorial).

Comment: @EyfI Do you check the console log, do you find `az login --service-principal -u **** -p **** -t ****`?

Comment: You could login on Jenkins VM with the same command. It should work. I test in my lab, it works for me.

Comment: The console shows `../script.sh: line 3: 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID: command not found'`
 
I logged in on my machine using the interactive login (only running az login and following the steps through the browser) but it didn't help.

Comment: @EyfI No, you should login with non-interactive login.  Replace `$AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` to your value. You add it to the screenshot.  I guess the root reason for your issue is your service principal does not have right permission. I suggest you could try.

Comment: @EyfI You could login with  interactive login, it does not mean you could successful with non-interactive login. Also, service principal does not support interactive login. When you execute `az login`, what account you enter, a Azure AD account or Microsoft account? I don't think you could enter service principal. `Client ID` and `Client Secret` is not your account user name and password.

Comment: The interactive account used my account, yes, I suppose that doesn't work.
I do have the Azure credentials filled out: http://imgur.com/YD9McrA But they don't seem to be valid (I didn't notice the verify button before). I don't know why though: The subscription ID is the ID of my subscription, the client ID is ID of the Azure AD application, the client secret is the generated key and the tenant ID after the endpoint is the Azure AD Directory ID. (Described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: @EyfI One more thing you could check, when you add Azure service principal to Jenkins credential, click `Verity Service Principal`, please ensure you could see `Successfully verified the Microsoft Azure Service Principal`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153428/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-eyfi).

Comment: @EyfI If possible, you could create a new service principal for Jenkins. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest#create-a-service-principal-for-your-application). Create a new service principal and give permission to it.

Comment: I assigned the application to a role, but I still get the provided credentials are not valid error. I'm not sure what about the credentials is incorrect though.

Comment: Could you try this command `az login --service-principal -u **** -p **** -t ****`? Replace correct client id, client secret, tenant id.

Comment: @EyfI Your account has co-admin permission?

Comment: `az login --service-principal -u **** -p **** -t ****` returns `http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided....` The client secret key was generated according to this part of the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal?view=azure-cli-latest#get-application-id-and-authentication-key

Comment: @EyfI It seems your client secret is wrong. `After saving the key, the value of the key is displayed. Copy this value because you are not able to retrieve the key later. You provide the key value with the application ID to log in as the application. Store the key value where your application can retrieve it.` The value is not password you enter.

Comment: If possible,could you create a new key, please ensure the key expire time.

Comment: But the lowest possible expire time is 1 year - how could the key be invalid already?

Comment: @EyfI Sorry, I am not sure. If I use a wrong key value. I get the similar error with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153733/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-eyfi).