# Error in Powershell Azure calls from Jenkins but not Powershell ISE?

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins

I run the following in PowerShell ISE    Connect-AzAccount and it works fine , but within Jenkins when run as a Powershell command I get  the following error:

The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.

Why would this happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to try out:

- You do not install AZ and Azure RM side by side , if you have it in the machine , please uninstall the Azure RM
- Please try running the following command in order:

  Install-Module Az
  Import-Module Az
  Connect-AzAccount

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/execute-cli-jenkins-pipeline

[Using Azure CLI in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979852/using-azure-cli-in-jenkins-pipeline)

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+CLI+Plugin

Hope it helps.